# MongoDB insertion is giving schema validation error

Tags: mongodb, validation, schema

I am new to `MongoDB`, I have written my `schema validation` but I am not able to `insert` data gives me `schema validation error`, code is shown below any help will be greatly appreciated.

**validator:**

```
    db.createCollection("kartCollection", {
     validator: {
       $jsonSchema: {
         bsonType: "object",
         required: [ "uid", "items" ],
         properties: {
            uid: {
               bsonType: "number",
               description: "holds user id"
            },
            items: {
               bsonType: "object",
               required: [ "itemid","qty","qty_type","cost","currency" ],
               properties: {
                  itemid: {
                    bsonType: "number",
                     description: "holds items id"
                  },
                  qty: {
                     bsonType: "number",
                     "description": "holds quantity of item"
                  },
                  qty_type: {
                     bsonType: "string",
                     "description": "holds quantity type like l,kl,kg gm,pcs"
                  },
                  cost: {
                     bsonType: "number",
                     "description": "holds cost of the selected item for quiker fetch"
                  },
                  currency: {
                     bsonType: "string",
                     "description": "holds currency of the item sold in "
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
});

db.kartCollection.insert({uid:'1',items:{{itemid:'1',qty:'1',qty_type:'kg',cost:'20',currency:'INR'}}});
```

**Error**

```
WriteResult({
            "nInserted" : 0,
            "writeError" : {
                    "code" : 121,
                    "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
            }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to insert this one

```
db.kartCollection.insert({uid:1,items:{ itemid:1,qty:1,qty_type:'kg',cost:20,currency:'INR'} });
```

your uid, itemid,qty,cost are of type Number and in above script you are trying to insert a String data.
Also items is of type object.